# Contrapositive of a statement involving integers

Tags: logic

If we need to write a contrapositive and negation for c and d are integers, then cd is an integer. So does it mean that c and d can be fractions or natural numbers for negation? I understand that contrapositive is making it to negative and back to positive but I can't make head or tails about integers part. I am new to this so please advise.

Comment: Contraposition and negation "apply" to statements and not to "objects" (number).

Comment: Hint: forget the content of the statement. Focus on writing it as $a\to b$, and then the contrapositive is $\lnot b\to\lnot a$.

Comment: the negation of "$c$ is an integer" will be "$c$ is **not** an integer"

Comment: Thus, "if $cd$ is **not** an integer, then either $c$ or $d$ are **not** integers"

Comment: I think I have an idea about contrapositive. I will try first. Thank you about the negation part and clarification, Mauro and Thank you Don for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "contrapositive" of "if A then B" is "if not B then not A".

Here, your statement is "if c and d are integers then cd is an integer"  so the contrapositive is "if cd is not an integer then c and d are not both integers".

That can be written more simply by using the fact that "not A and B" is the same as "not A or not B".

If cd is not an integer then either c is not an integer or d is not an integer.